# Returning HttpStatuscode for error from ActionFilters in WebAPI2

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, action-filter

I am in WebAPI .netCore environment and I am using ActionFilters for some JWT authorization code. Now, My code when any error occurs looks like below:

`context.Result = new JsonResult(new { Error = "JWT Token is expired."});`

The problem with this code is that it still throws statuscode 200. I want to it to fail at HTTP level and throw statuscode 400. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`BadRequestObjectResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.badrequestobjectresult?view=aspnetcore-2.1) will return a 400.

```
public class MyActionFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(new {Error = "JWT Token is expired."});
    }
}
```